# ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob - no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm attempting to get fixtures working for ActiveStorage while using Rspec, on Rails 7.

Here's the relationship:

```
# models/recording.rb
class Recordings
   has_one_attached :file
```

I've got the set-up recommended in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/active_storage_overview.html#adding-attachments-to-fixtures):

```
# config/storage.yml
test_fixtures:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage_fixtures") %>
```

```
# spec/fixtures/active_storage/attachments.yml
recording_file:
  name: file
  record: review (Recording) # This exists in fixtures
  blob: recording_file_blob
```

```
# spec/fixtures/active_storage/blobs.yml
recording_file_blob: <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob(
  filename: "test.jpg", # exists at spec/fixtures/files/test.jpg
  service_name: "test_fixtures") %>
```

However when running rspec, I get `no implicit conversion of nil into String`

It points to the error being here:
`activestorage-7.0.3.1/lib/active_storage/fixture_set.rb:68:in` prepare'`

And [that line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activestorage/lib/active_storage/fixture_set.rb#L68) seems to suggest that I'm missing a filename? But I'm clearly not?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/active_storage_overview.html#adding-attachments-to-fixtures) say the default path is `test/fixtures/files`, Maybe you need to make some config to use `spec/fixtures/files`.

---

Or you can just use [rspec file-fixture](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/5-1/docs/file-fixture)